# Cake build: access original command line arguments string?

Tags: c#, command-line-arguments, cakebuild

While trying to squeeze [Mono.Options](https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinComponents/tree/master/XPlat/Mono.Options) into my Cake script, I noticed I wasn't entirely sure how to give it the original arguments string from the command line call that launched the Cake script in the first place. Mono.Options `Parse` method takes what would be a typical console app's `string[] args` parameter, so I need to feed it something it can work with.

I know I can query the context for specific arguments with ArgumentAlias calls, but is there any way to access the entire original string calling string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cake scripts are essentially just a regular .NET Process to you can access it through `System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()`

### Example PoC

Quick n dirty example of one way you could use Mono.Options with Cake below

```
#addin nuget:?package=Mono.Options&version=5.3.0.1
using Mono.Options;

public static class MyOptions
{
    public static bool ShouldShowHelp { get; set; } = false;
    public static List<string> Names { get; set; } = new List<string>();
    public static int Repeat { get; set; } = 1;
}

var p = new OptionSet {
            { "name=",    "the name of someone to greet.",                          n => MyOptions.Names.Add (n) },
            { "repeat=",  "the number of times to MyOptions.Repeat the greeting.",  (int r) => MyOptions.Repeat = r },
            // help is reserved cake command so using options instead
            { "options",     "show this message and exit",                             h => MyOptions.ShouldShowHelp = h != null },
        };

try {
    p.Parse (
        System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()
        // Skip Cake.exe and potential cake file.
        // i.e. "cake --name="Mattias""
        //  or "cake build.cake --name="Mattias""
        .SkipWhile(arg=>arg.EndsWith(".exe", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)||arg.EndsWith(".cake", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        .ToArray()
    );
}
catch (OptionException e) {
    Information("Options Sample: ");
    Information (e.Message);
    Information ("--options' for more information.");
    return;
}

if (MyOptions.ShouldShowHelp || MyOptions.Names.Count == 0)
{
    var sw = new StringWriter();
    p.WriteOptionDescriptions (sw);
    Information(
        "Usage: [OPTIONS]"
        );
    Information(sw);
    return;
}

string message = "Hello {0}!";

foreach (string name in MyOptions.Names) {
    for (int i = 0; i < MyOptions.Repeat; ++i)
        Information (message, name);
}
```

### Example output

`cake .\Mono.Options.cake` will output help as no names specified

[image: no arguments]

`cake .\Mono.Options.cake --options` will output "help"

[image: nane specified]

`cake .\Mono.Options.cake --name=Mattias` will greet me

[image: name specified]

`cake .\Mono.Options.cake --name="Mattias" --repeat=5` will greet me 5 times

[image: name and repeat specified]

`cake .\Mono.Options.cake --name="Mattias" --repeat=sdss` will fail and report because repeat not a number

[image]